# How can i speed up count of big Linq query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have some lists of byte arrays that I combine/check each other with Linq. Those lists and arrays can be different in length. The problem is when i try to count the results. Also if I added the `.Take(1)` clause things doesn't changes. I'll post some code for better understanding.Function `Permute()` give me back all the permutations of that specific array.

```
List<byte[]> firstList =new List<byte[]>();
List<byte[]> secondList=new List<byte[]>();
List<byte[]> thirdList =new List<byte[]>();

 IEnumerable<byte[]> sql = (
                            from rid in firstList
                            from s in secondList
                            from p in thirdList
                            from per in Permute(s)
                            where per.SequenceEqual(p)
                            select rid  
                           );

IEnumerable<byte[]> result = (from s in sql
                              where sql.Count(item =>item.SequenceEqual(s)) == 10
                              select s.ToArray()
                             ).Take(1);
if (result.Count() != 0)
{
  byte[] myByte=result.First();
//Do something
}
```

When I execute `result.Count()!=0` and `myByte=result.First()` waiting time can took an hour, also if I limit list( first ten elements, second 150 and third 200) .
So, is there any way to speed up the count or alternatively to check if `result` contains something in a "rapid" way?

Comment: Why are you writing `from per in Permute(s)
                            where per.SequenceEqual(p)`?

Comment: Because I need to check also every permutation of every element of the second list

Comment: But you're then filtering to use only the permutation which is equal to `p`.  That defeats the purpose.

Comment: Try to use Any() in place of Count() != 0.

Comment: @SLaks My bad. secondList can depends from first, so i want to obtain all cases where a single permutations of secondList is contained in ThirdList. I can't use .Contains() because they are array, so it would compare only references, and because array{4,5} is completely different from array{5,4} (I think)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cut your time in half by calling `result.FirstOrDefault()`, which will return `null` if there are no results.

This means you only need to iterate once, and it means you never need to iterate over the entire collection (unlike `.Count()`)

---

You can also make the query itself faster by writing an efficient `IEqualityComparer<byte[]>` and calling `sql.ToLookup()` instead of `.Count()` in the second query.

Comment: But doesn't the comparer slows down the research if it has to be looped hundreds of time? (I really don't know, I'm relatively newbie to programmation )

Comment: @AnthonyStarkPirrone: You're already looping hundreds of types.  The comparer allows you to replace one layer of loops with a hash lookup.